# Which type of markdown is Stack Overflow using?

Tags: discussion, markdown

Precisely which type of markdown (afaik there are quite a few variants) and editor (the one I am typing in right now) is Stack Overflow using?

I understand, there must be a JavaScript realtime implementation (which shows me the preview below). Where could I get that?

I hope there's also a PHP implementation, so I can turn markdown into HTML in the backend?

Ultimately I want to turn a very proprietary wordpress theme into being markdown based, since I find this the exact right balance between complexity and ease of use. Many 'wiki syntaxes' are in my opinion off to one side or the other.

Comment: The de facto standard Markdown library for PHP is [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/).

Comment: See [We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/289905). The answers here are (mostly) obsolete now. (They still use some of their own Markdown implementations for Stack-Exchange-specific features.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for:

- [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) - C# Markdown processor
- [pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) - A JavaScript Markdown converter and editor
- [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) - A Javascript module and CSS file that allows syntax highlighting of source code snippets in an html page.

You can find the full supported Markdown syntax in the [editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Don't forget [Jeff's HTML Sanitizer](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html).

Comment: Thank you. I also found something at http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/  (not yet tested about compatibility differences)

Answer (score 3):

StackExchange uses the [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) implementation, written in C#. Converting it to php would likely be quite the task.

See also: [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)